# Generate Json of Map in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a class in groovy:

```
public enum EnumStatus{
    GREY,
    YELLOW,
    RED,
    GREEN
}

public class Status {
    private EnumStatus myStatus = EnumStatus.GREY
    private List<String> failures = []
    
    public Status(EnumStatus status, List<String> failureList) {
        myStatus = status
        failures = failureList
    }

    public EnumStatus getStatus() {
        return myStatus
    }

    public void setStatus(EnumStatus status) {
        myStatus = status
    }

    public void addFailure(String failure) {
        failures.add(failure)
    }
}
```

I am trying to generate the json of Map defined as this:

```
Status status11 = new Status()
Status status12 = new Status(RED,["myFailure"])
Map myMap = ["myId11": status11, "myId12": status12]
JsonOutput.toJson(myMap)
```

The print looks like this

```
["myId11":{"status":"GREY"},"myId12":{"status":"RED"}]
```

I don't understand why the JsonOutput.toJson doesn't show the list of failures.
Is there a method or an interface to implement to have a proper json ?

P.S: I am running the groovy script in a jenkins pipeline

Comment: Add public method `getFailures()`

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `failures` explicitly as `private` so that it cannot be accessed from the outside.

You could add a custom `getFailures()` method following @daggett's suggestion, or you could let Groovy create getters and setters for you.
If you omit `private`, Groovy automatically marks the property as `private` and silently creates `getFailures()` and `setFailures()`. If you don't want the setter for `failures`, you can define it as `final`.

Likewise, you could let Groovy do the work for `getStatus()` and `setStatus()` if you are okay with renaming the property to `status`.

```
class Status {
    EnumStatus status
    final List<String> failures

    Status(EnumStatus status=EnumStatus.GREY, List<String> failureList=[]) {
        this.status = status
        failures = failureList
    }

    void addFailure(String failure) {
        failures.add(failure)
    }
}
```

If you want Groovy to do more work for you, check out [`@Canonical`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Canonical.html)

```
@Canonical
class Status {
    EnumStatus status = EnumStatus.GREY
    final List<String> failures = []

    void addFailure(String failure) {
        failures.add(failure)
    }
}
```